# How to modify Laravel Authorization without password when do login?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0. I want login using auth laravel, but I only need to input the username when login (no need email and/or password). And I have changed the code into these below.

In my `LoginController`:

```
public function getLogin(){
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return view('auth.login');  
    }
    else{
        return redirect('home');
    }
}

public function postLogin(){

    Auth::attempt([
        'USER_NAME' => Input::get('username')
    ]);

    return redirect('home');
}
```

In my `User` model:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {
use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

protected $table = 'MS_USER_ROLE';

}
```

And I have got an error:

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 111:
>   Undefined index: password

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You'll have to edit the Trait it uses.

Comment: what do you mean 'Trait it uses'?

Comment: If you don't know what that means you will not be able to edit it. Can't you just add a password to the attempt method and fake it?

Comment: yeah you're right, I did that in my previous project. This will be my last option if I'm not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

You want to use the `Auth::login()` method to explicitly log them in.

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $user = User::where('USER_NAME', '=', Input::get('username'))->firstOrFail();
    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: Can I get a data in my User Table using `Auth::user()->CREATED_DATE` (for example) if I used that ?

Comment: Yes, setting the user with `Auth::login()` enables accessing that same user via `Auth::user()` down the track.

Comment: Could you tell me how? because I have got an error `Trying to get property of non-object ` when I success login, because of `@if(Auth::user()->ROLE_ID == '1')
            <li>
              <a href="{{ url ('Menu') }}">
                <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <span>Menu</span>
              </a>
            </li>
@endif` . I have a ROLE_ID column in my user table.

Comment: That should work fine. You will need to debug to confirm that a user has actually been logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Just log them in manually if you're authenticating by username:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $user = User::whereUsername(request('username'))->firstOrFail():

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect('home');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users